# Extracting from <class 'haystack.schema.Answer'>

Tags: python, haystack

I have an answer from the Haystack framework, which is: <Answer: answer='major mild ncd', score=0.09601292014122009, context='d neurocognitive disorder due hiv infection functi...'> The type of it is <class 'haystack.schema.Answer'>. How to extract the context and the score from it?

I cannot access the elements as for lists or dictionaries

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Haystack docs](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/v1.25/docs/documents_answers_labels) (just search for `haystack.schema.Answer` to see the example code), you can directly access the values by using -

```
score = answer.score
context = answer.context
```

where answer is your `haystack.schema.Answer` object